# Voltage/Current ratings for dual SCR modules

Tags: pulse, high-power

I'm working with a different kind of package of SCR than what I'm used to, where there are two SCR's in one package. So the Datasheet for this SCR-module only has one rating for voltage and current, BUT is that rating for BOTH SCR's in series, or is the rating for each SCR? I'm confused.

The SCR I'm working with is an Infineon TT570N16KOF, and I'd like to know if the voltage rating of 1600V is for each of the two SCR's in the package, making it 3200V that if I use them in series (between pins/pads 2 and 3)?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage rating should be for each SCR because in the half-bridge configuration of your component, there will be modes of operation where one SCR will be on and the other will be off and subject to the full voltage. You could only ever use it at 3200V if you just used it as both SCRs collectively as a single switch and not a half-bridge, and that's not what the device is intended for since it has a tap out between the two SCRs.

Just like how an H-bridge that is always off can have double the voltage of the MOSFETs applied across it, but it certainly can't operate at double the voltage rating of the MOSFETs used.

It doesn't matter what the current rating the datasheet says for solid state switches (BJTs, MOSFET, IGBTs, thyristors, diodes, etc). Those are basically imaginary numbers based on laboratory, and sometimes even unattainable theoretical conditions. You need to calculate your losses using your current and the specifications provided and then use that with the package thermal resistance and your heatsinking specifications to ensure you remain within the operating temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm using this SCR because I found them cheap on ebay haha. And I'm using them for a pulse supply to a coil, discharging a decent-sized cap(50-100uF) at around 800-3000V. I'm still learning as I go here in terms of measuring such high currents(a few kA), and if you have suggestions for it, I'd love to hear! I also have heard that snubbers are necessary for driving inductive coils like mine for IGBT's but not sure if I need them for SCR's.

Comment: @zmcginty SCRs are no different but they are hardier.

Answer (score 1):

The TT570N16KOF has two thyristors in modules. The datasheet has single thyristor rating values.

[TT570N16KOF Datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TT570N16KOF-DataSheet-v03_02-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b42f96354c4e)

For higher voltages (3200 V) you can connect them in series, the series connection recommendations are given in the below application note.

[AN2012-01](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN20012_01_Bipolar_Technical_Information-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b40ec42b126a)

Comment: Guru_Infineon - Hi, As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, including the rule for [referencing](/help/referencing) any copied/adapted material, and [no signatures](/help/behavior) (so I removed it). || Also, you seem to be representing Infineon, so please see [this site rule on promotions](/help/promotion). You must include a clear disclosure of your association with Infineon inside any question or answer where you use, mention, link or even hint at anything related to Infineon or associated companies, products, websites etc.

Comment: So if you work for Infineon, then in any post (like your answer here) connected in any way to Infineon or associated companies, products, websites etc. you need to include something like: "Disclosure: I work for Infineon". You need to be accurate in the disclosure statement, so please consider what you say. Please [edit] your answer to add that. (In case you were going to ask, having the word "Infineon" in your username is not enough, since usernames can be changed. The disclosure of being affiliated with something related to a post, needs to be a statement within the text of the post itself.)

Comment: Also be careful not to be seen to promote their products, website, services etc. excessively, as excessive promotion can be interpreted as spam and treated that way (which can affect your account). Thanks.